# Capture image action only works sometimes without clear reason why

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am using cameraKit to handle my camera activity. My problem right now is that sometimes it works just fine and other times it won't at all.
I've inserted a bunch of Log prints as you could see in the code bellow. Sometimes it will run through all the logs and sometimes would just print the "button clicked one".

Can't figure out why it is not consistent:

*I've tried running and re-running it about 0 times for the sake of checking without changing anything, and it was not consistent.

```
class CameraFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var cameraKitView: CameraKitView

    private lateinit var localImageViewModel: LocalImageViewModel

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        activity?.let {
            localImageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LocalImageViewModel::class.java)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(co.getdere.R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false)


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val mActivity = activity as CameraActivity

        cameraKitView = view.findViewById(co.getdere.R.id.camera_view)
        cameraKitView.aspectRatio = 0.8f

        val captureButton = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(co.getdere.R.id.camera_btn)

        captureButton.setOnClickListener {

            Log.d("photoActivity", "button clicked")


            cameraKitView.captureImage { _, image ->

                Log.d("photoActivity", "image captured")


                val timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
                val fileName = "Dere$timeStamp.jpg"

                val path =
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + File.separator + "Dere"
                val outputDir = File(path)
                outputDir.mkdir()
                val savedPhoto = File(path + File.separator + fileName)

                Log.d("photoActivity", "new file created")

                try {
                    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(savedPhoto.path)
                    outputStream.write(image)
                    outputStream.close()
                    mActivity.sendBroadcast(Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(savedPhoto)))

                    Log.d("photoActivity", "Image saved to file and system rescaned the device")
                 Glide.with(this).load(savedPhoto).into(mActivity.photoEditorFragment.view!!.findViewById(R.id.photo_editor_image))

                    Log.d("photoActivity", "image loaded into new fragment")


                    mActivity.switchVisibility(1)

                    Log.d("photoActivity", "visibility switched")


                    val localImagePost = LocalImagePost(2343, savedPhoto.path)
                    Log.d("photoActivity", "Took photo")

                    localImageViewModel.insert(localImagePost)


                } catch (e: java.io.IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Log.d("photoActivity", "failed to take photo")

                }

            }
        }
    }


    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        cameraKitView.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        cameraKitView.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        cameraKitView.onPause()
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        cameraKitView.onStop()
        super.onStop()
    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        cameraKitView.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        stopRepeatingTask()
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): CameraFragment = CameraFragment()
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using it for some other app, I do have advice for you. Use the non-beta version. Works perfectly. Current Version: v0.13.4
Docs are outdated though.

New usage:

```
    cameraKit.addCameraKitListener(object : CameraKitEventListener {
            override fun onVideo(video: CameraKitVideo?) {
                Log.i("camera", "onVideo")
            }

            override fun onEvent(event: CameraKitEvent?) {
                Log.i("camera", "onEvent: $event")
            }

            override fun onImage(capturedImage: CameraKitImage?) {
                Log.i("camera", "onImage")
                capturedImage?.let { image ->
                    cameraViewModel.saveAndCompressImage(image.jpeg)
                }
            }

            override fun onError(e: CameraKitError?) {
                Log.i("camera", "onError: ${e?.exception}")
            }
        })
```